# I can not use array properties in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
allBondedWarehouse1: any;
```

in this way, there is a variant that meets any type

```
this.allBondedWarehouse = new DataSource({
      load: (loadOptions) => {


        return this.service.getBondedWarehouseTrioKeyValueGridData(null).toPromise().then(response => {
          debugger;
          this.allBondedWarehouse1 = response;
          //this.allBondedWarehouse1 = new ArrayStore({
          //  data: response,
          //  key: 'id'
          //});


          this.bondedWarehouseIdsStirng = this.requestModel.bondedWarehouseIds.split(',');

          for (var item in this.bondedWarehouseIdsStirng) {
            if (parseInt(item)) {
               //this.allBondedWarehouseGridData.push(item);
              this.addBondedWarehouse(parseInt(item));
            }
          }

          return response;
        }
        )
      }
    });
```

I did a couple of steps as shown and threw the variable return variable.

```
 <div class="form-group" [hidden]="isImportCreate">
                        <bl-atlas-common-bonded-warehouse-grid [placeHolder]="'Antrepo'"
                                                               [(bindModel)]="requestModel.bondedWarehouseId"
                                                               [isValidated]="true"
                                                               (customHouseIdChange)="customHouseIdChange($event)"
                                                               (bindModelChange)="addBondedWarehouse($event)"></bl-atlas-common-bonded-warehouse-grid>
```

I'm triggering a method with this component bindModelChange.

```
addBondedWarehouse(event) {
    var bw = this.allBondedWarehouse1.filter(x => x.id === event).allBondedWarehouse1_types;


    debugger;

    if (bw != null) {
      if (this.allBondedWarehouseGridData.filter(x => x.id == bw.id).length == 0) {
        this.allBondedWarehouseGridData.push(bw);
        this.addOfferBondedWarehouseList.push(bw.id);
      }

    }
    //this.requestModel.customHouseIds = null;


  }
```

I can not filter on this line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSpyh.png)

In this picture, if the bw variable is undefined and x => x.id is undefined, can you help?

Comment: var bw = this.allBondedWarehouse1.filter(x => x.id === event);   it does not work that way either.

Comment: Is .allBondedWarehouse1_types a property of your object? The filter function returns an array so you should use an index like this.allBondedWarehouse1.filter(x => x.id === event)[0].allBondedWarehouse1_types

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It took me a while, I'm filling the current sequence with another area.

```
var bw = this.allBondedWarehouse1.filter(x => x.id == event.id);
```

the above code snippet solved my problem. Thank you for your time. I hope no one will fall into such an obvious fault, even if you made an error does not waste so much time.